# Loading of the custom configuration section issue

Tags: c#

I have an issue with loading from the custom configuration section.

What is the problematic part. I have two elements (First and Second) that I have defined under the XSD schema within the choice element. User can choose only one when he/she is configuring. Let say something like this :

```
<customSection>
  <First attribute ="test" />    
</customSection>
```

or

```
<customSection>
  <Second attribute ="test" attribute2 ="np" />  
</customSection>
```

When I load that configuration, in both cases configuration elements First and Second will be loaded, they will not be null (objects will be empty).
How to accomplish, per instance in first case, that Second object is null ?

Thank you

Comment: What is the specific problem?  what have you tried?

Comment: In first case per instance I will loaded in code CustomSection object and within First object (as an property) with sub-properties and also Second object (as property )that will not be null. It will initialized with empty properties. I am expecting that Second object is null. That is what I want to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I needed. Each configuration element has property ElementInformation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.elementinformation.aspx), where is further present property *IsPresent* that indicates does specific configuration element was present in configuration file. Official description :

IsPresent : Gets a value indicating whether the associated ConfigurationElement object is in the configuration file.

With this I can track which elements are loaded and which one are not. Previously I could not say is something equal or not with null. It will be never equal with null independently with that does it has values.

Answer (score 2):

First you create class of mapping

```
public class YourCustomConfig : ConfigurationSection 
{
 ....
}
```

full sample here : http://nnish.com/2009/09/17/custom-configuration-section-in-c/

Second you get your datas

```
YourCustomConfig section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customSection") as YourCustomConfig;
```

Comment: Yes Frederique, I know that. I have everything defined. Problem is that YourCustomConfig  in your case will initialize all of the complex objects (its properties), regardless are these defined in configuration file or not. For me, expected behavior is that these objects are set to null, not empty initialized.